# Master page menu required to persist state across pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page menu which gets called across various content pages. How do I maintain the state of my menu across various content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the menu state changes, store the current state in Session.

At the beginning of the non-postback part of your master's page_load, set the menu settings to whatever is found in Session.

You may or may not want/need to put default settings into Session in the session_start event of global.asax, depending on the default menu state.